# How can I programmatically select multiple rows in ag-Grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an array of row ids, stored in `tempSelected`, and I would like to programmatically set each row in the list to selected. This is what I'm trying:

```
let len = tempSelected.length;
this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (node) {
  for(let i=0; i<len; i++){
    if(node.id === tempSelected[i]){
      node.setSelected(true);
    }
  }
});
```

At the end of this loop, I want every row in `tempSelected` to be selected, but right now, only the last id in the `tempSelected` array gets selected, and the others are not.

I have set `rowSelection = 'multiple'`, so it shouldn't be limited to 1 selection. I have also tried changing `node.setSelected(true);` to `node.setSelected(true, false);` based on what I read [here on ag-grid's website](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/), but that didn't change the result.

How can I select multiple nodes at once?

Comment: Is node.id type same as tempSelected data type?

Comment: @Aamir Yes, I put a console.log statement inside that if statement, and when tempSelected has 3 values, the log is printed 3 times.

Comment: That's strange, I have been doing something similar and it works, just to confirm, you are setting gridOptions.rowSelection = 'multiple' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that is because you handled the highlighting of the rows on the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, or ag-grid's `gridReady` event. Both of the events are not suitable, as the `ngOnInit` hook is fired when initialisation has completed, and `gridReady` is triggered when the grid itself is ready (but the data is not rendered yet).

Therefore, to be safe, and assuming you want to handle the highlighting on load, you should use the `firstDataRendered` event instead.

For your case, you can bind the `firstDataRendered` event to some method, such as `onFirstDataRendered`. Also, do make sure that `rowSelection` is binded to `multiple` to allow multiple selections.

```
<ag-grid-angular
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
  [rowSelection]="'multiple'"

  // other events and props
></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
onFirstDataRendered(params) {
  let len = tempSelected.length;
  this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
    for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
      if(node.id === tempSelected[i]){
        node.setSelected(true);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/krILbACu4pgxJhFVKFJM?p=preview).